# How can I execute lua code without using loadstring?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to be able to execute lua code without using loadstring.
If anyone could help that'd be amazing

Comment: Your question need more details, such as where this code is coming from, how it needs to be run, what will this code do? and most importantly what have you tried?

Comment: The point of removing loadstring is to keep you from doing this. Why exactly do you want to?

Comment: Roblox' Lua [only has loadstring](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/Lua-Globals) (no `require`, `loadfile` or `load`), which makes it impossible to execute code without using it (unless you would happen to know some kind of precious RCE vulnerability).

Comment: You could write a Lua interpreter in Lua :)

Comment: @LMD, Roblox Lua comes with `require` for ModuleScripts. See https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/modulescripts

Comment: @Kylaaa oh, wasn't aware of that (weird that it's not listed under the globals section in the docs), I'm not familiar with Roblox Lua. Consider making that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to execute code through a script is using loadscript, if you want to execute code through presets, I suggest you research [ModuleScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ModuleScript)